# How to save web response in file?

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to save json web response in a file. I'm able to create and save the file , but I can't get the  web response data in it. In the file there's only this : `[object Object]`

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

}

nodes: any;
ngOnInit(): void {
  // Make the HTTP request:
  this.http.get('http://someUrl').subscribe(data => {
    // Read the result field from the JSON response.
    this.nodes = data;
    this.downloadFile(this.nodes);

  });

}

downloadFile(data){
  let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8;' });
  let dwldLink = document.createElement("a");
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let isSafariBrowser = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1;
  if (isSafariBrowser) {  //if Safari open in new window to save file with random filename.
  dwldLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
  }
  dwldLink.setAttribute("href", url);
  dwldLink.setAttribute("download", "TEST.txt");
  dwldLink.style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.body.appendChild(dwldLink);
  dwldLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(dwldLink);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to translate the object into its string representation. One way it could be done is by means of `JSON.stringify`.

```
let blob = new Blob([ JSON.stringify(data) ], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8;' });
```

<strike>It's a wild guess, but I'm expecting your `data` object to be a `response`. Therefore, you may need to call `.json()` on it to retrieve the actual payload:</strike>

```
this.http.get('http://someUrl').subscribe(data => {
  // Read the result field from the JSON response.
  this.nodes = data;
  this.downloadFile(this.nodes);
});
```

Since you're using some `HttpClient` instead of a standard `Http` service, it's hard to tell. The code for file download you show matches what I have working in one [of my projects](https://github.com/another-guy/randvizer/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts#L159).

Debugging hint could you put a breakpoint on line `this.nodes = data.json();` and do `JSON.stringify(data)` in your browser console? Then update your question with the output. It will help understanding what object you're *in fact* dealing with.

Comment: I tried it, but I got this error: Property 'json' does not exist  on type 'Object'.

Comment: It's working now, thanks, you might wanna edit your answer

Comment: @eli Updated the answer